# WP7 Isolated Storage when app is updated

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I’m storing data that my app uses in **isolated storage** which is working fine. However, I’m not sure what will happen to the data **when I release an update to my app** – is the isolated storage data cleared? or will I still be able to access the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your isolated storage is untouched via an app update.

It's your app's responsibility to manage any updates needed to keep app version and data in sync.